# How to add data to Array list that is linked to a recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin

Good day. So I am trying to add data to my tables by an action. I currently have it is static and would like to know the best way to insert data. My end goal is for a driver to be selected and based on the driver name that was selected it will pull that drivers deliveries for the day. I have seen post about fragments but don't know if that will be relevant to me.

MainActivity

```
package com.dispatch.tripsheet


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private var dbHandler: DBHandler? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerViewTripsheetlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        recyclerViewTripsheetlist.adapter = TableViewAdapter(Tripsheetlist)


//This is for the drivers. Drivers still need to be pulled from the database
        val list : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        list.add("Deon")
        list.add("Leon")
        list.add("David")
        list.add("Dick")
        list.add("Jim")
        list.add("Harry")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter( this, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list)
        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spnDriver)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                val item :String = list[p2]
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Driver $item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                //empty
            }

            //insert code that activates data pull of tripsheet for driver= actifavte by method the class/object that activates the data pull. so datapuul(Driver)


        }
        limitDropDownHeight(spinner)
 //drivers end

        val btnLoadData: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnLoadData)


        weightsum(tvTotalweight, Tripsheetlist)
        totaldelNotes(tvTotaldelv,Tripsheetlist)
        setData(btnLoadData,Tripsheetlist)


    }
      val Tripsheetlist = ArrayList<DataModel>().apply {


        add(DataModel(190617, 182832, "", 0,"", "",""))
          // Need one row for dummy data. Gets removed so chance wont be seen.
        add(DataModel(190617, 182832, "Jcorp", 100,"Delivery done", "Delivery not done",""))
        add(DataModel(190617, 182833, "Honda", 100,"No exceptions", "Exceptions",""))
        add(DataModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"100%", "50%",""))
        add(DataModel(190617, 182832, "Panado", 300,"OK", "NO",""))
        add(DataModel(190617, 182832, "Gheiters", 100,"Success", "Failed",""))
        add(DataModel(190617, 182832, "John", 300,"Yes", "No",""))

    // need to change from hardcoded text to input

          //these values will change from sql input
          var a  = 10000
          var b  = 10000
          var c   = "Absa"
          var d = 50
          var e = "No exceptions"
          var f = "Exceptions"
          var g = ""

            // value to changes based on data size.
          var x: Int = 29


          for (i in 20..x)
          {
            add(DataModel(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))

              a++
          }
        //  })

     }
//setData is not 100% ready
    private fun setData(btnLoadData: Button, Tripsheetlist: ArrayList<DataModel>) {

    btnLoadData.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
var x: Int = 2
        for (i in 3..6)
        {       //does not work
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].WOrder  = 20022
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].DElNote  = 20022
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Company     = "FNB"
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Weight  = 20
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Button1 = "No exceptions"
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Button2 = "Exceptions"
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].tvdone = ""
            x++
        }

        btnLoadData.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.green))

     }


    })

    }
//works
    fun weightsum(args: TextView, Tripsheetlist: ArrayList<DataModel>) {
        var totweight: Int = 0
        var sum: Int = 0

        for (i in 0 until Tripsheetlist.size -1) {
            sum +=  Tripsheetlist[i].Weight
        }

        totweight = sum
        tvTotalweight.setText("Total Weight: " + totweight + "kg")

    }
//works
    fun totaldelNotes(tvTotaldelv: TextView?, Tripsheetlist: ArrayList<DataModel>) {
        var totnotes: Int = 1
        var sum: Int = 0

        //  var input: String
        totnotes = Tripsheetlist.size -1


        tvTotaldelv?.setText("Total Delivery Notes: " +totnotes)
    }
//works
    fun limitDropDownHeight(spinner: Spinner){
        val popup = Spinner::class.java.getDeclaredField( "mPopup")
        popup.isAccessible = true
        val popupWindow = popup.get(spinner)as ListPopupWindow
        popupWindow.height = (200 * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
    }
}
```

TableViewAdapter

```
package com.dispatch.tripsheet



    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.table_list_item.view.*

class TableViewAdapter( var Tripsheetlist: List<DataModel> = emptyList()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TableViewAdapter.RowViewHolder>() {
                  //  var dataItems: List<DataModel> = emptyList()



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RowViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.table_list_item, parent, false)
        return RowViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return Tripsheetlist.size// + 1 // one more to add header row
    }

    private  fun updateData(data: List<DataModel>) {
        Tripsheetlist = data
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RowViewHolder, position: Int) {



        val rowPos = holder.adapterPosition
        val dataItem = Tripsheetlist[position]




        if (rowPos == 0) {
            // Header Cells. Main Headings appear here
            holder.itemView.apply {
                setHeaderBg(txtWOrder)
                setHeaderBg(txtDElNote)
                setHeaderBg(txtCompany)
              //  setHeaderBg(txtAddress)
                setHeaderBg(txtWeight)
               setHeaderBg(txtbutton1)
                setHeaderBg(txtbutton2)
                setHeaderBg(txttvdone)


                txtWOrder.text = "WOrder"
                txtDElNote.text = "DElNote"
                txtCompany.text = "Company"
               // txtAddress.text = "Address"
                txtWeight.text = "Weight"
                txtbutton1.text = "Delivered"
                txtbutton2.text = "Exception"
                txttvdone.text = ""
            }
        } else {
            val modal = Tripsheetlist[rowPos ]

            holder.itemView.apply {
                setContentBg(txtWOrder)
                setContentBg(txtDElNote)
                setContentBg(txtCompany)
              //  setContentBg(txtAddress)
                setContentBg(txtWeight)
                setContentBg(txtbutton1)
                setContentBg(txtbutton2)
                setContentBg(txttvdone)

                txtWOrder.text = modal.WOrder.toString()
                txtDElNote.text = modal.DElNote.toString()
                txtCompany.text = modal.Company.toString()
              //  txtAddress.text = modal.Address.toString()
                txtWeight.text = modal.Weight.toString()
                txtbutton1.text = modal.Button1.toString()
                txtbutton2.text = modal.Button2.toString()
                txttvdone.text = modal.tvdone.toString()
            }
        }


        holder.txttvdone.apply {
            setBackgroundResource(when (dataItem.state) {
                DataState.Unselected -> android.R.color.transparent
                DataState.Success -> R.color.green
                DataState.Failure -> R.color.orange
            })
            text = when (dataItem.state) {
                DataState.Unselected -> ""
                DataState.Success -> "✓"
                DataState.Failure -> "x"
                //this is where I add code to export data through api maybe add it in the datastate set where it is success and Failure
            }
        }

        holder.apply {
            txtbutton1.setOnClickListener {
                Log.e("Clicked", "Successful delivery")
                //this is where I add code to export data through api
                dataItem.state = DataState.Success
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            txtbutton2.setOnClickListener {
                Log.e("Clicked", "Exception on delivery")

                dataItem.state = DataState.Failure
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

    }
     class RowViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

         val txttvdone:TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txttvdone)
         val txtbutton1:Button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.txtbutton1)
         val txtbutton2:Button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.txtbutton2)
     }

    class MyViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        var txtbutton1 = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.txtbutton1)
        val txtbutton2:Button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.txtbutton2)
        var txttvdone = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txttvdone)
    }


    private fun setHeaderBg(view: View) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg)
    }

    private fun setContentBg(view: View) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg)
    }

}
```

I have created something with a button just to test it out. But what happens is. The data only changes after clicking the load data button and then a button on my recycler view, which is not ideal.

```
 btnLoadData.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
var x: Int = 2
        for (i in 3..6)
        {       //does not work
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].WOrder  = 20022
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].DElNote  = 20022
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Company     = "FNB"
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Weight  = 20
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Button1 = "No exceptions"
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].Button2 = "Exceptions"
            this.Tripsheetlist[x].tvdone = ""
            x++
        }
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Let me know if any additional information is needed.
For my layouts. I have a activity main with my recycler view and then a table list item for my rows. Below is how my app looks.

[image: How my app looked before I added the load data button.]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this,

1. add a setData method to RV , so your part of code looks like

```
class TableViewAdapter(){
    private var data : List<DataModel> = emptyList()
    
    fun setData( newData : List<..>){
        data = newData
        notifyDataSetChanged() // and handle other events to update
    }
}
```

then you can update data on go

2. use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) supported RV like ListAdapter or implement it yourself